# Install yamdi, ffmpeg, mplayer, mencoder and mediainfo

Tags: ssh, ffmpeg, mplayer, mencoder, mediainfo

Regards, 
For one a script I need the following support to have on the my server.

- Mencoder 1.0rc1
- Mplayer 1.0rc1
- FFmpeg (from SVN)
- flvtool2 or yamdi
- MediaInfo (http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)

How do I check what I got from this on server? 
And how can I install over SSH if its no on server?

Comment: FFmpeg has not used SVN for years. Questions on server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your server, if it is a Debian/Ubuntu distribution or similar:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg mplayer mencoder mediainfo yamdi
```